# Concurrent access with activiti while excuting jobs on act_ru_job table

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, activiti

I'm having an issue while launching an app that's using activiti. it just stops at some point after launching activiti jobExecuter and stays that way.
The only time I can get it to start is when I launch it with the debug mode, and even then it is random, so my best guess is that it's concurrent access related.
Could it be it ? and if so, isn't activiti supposed to handle access to its database tables ?

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: I think anyone would be guessing at this point.  We'll need some more information in order help you.

Comment: @AnisKoukabi, you need to find a way to debug this further to see what's happening. What have you tried so far? try jstack to get a thread dump. This will give you an idea on what each thread is doing and it will even tell you if there is a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: Yes, activiti handles access to its tables.
Could it be stopping at a user task? Perhaps these is something in your business process that's causing the execution to pause.

Comment: @UncleRico What information do you need ?

Comment: @Mustafa The problem is in the act_ru_job table, when it is not empty randomly the application blocks on start. When it does actully start, this particular table is empty and others are being populated.
At first, the app is deployed on a remote server, so I've made a copy of the database and launched it on localhost, It did blocked on run, and then when I started debuguing, It just work out of nowhere, Ive just put som debug points. Then Ive compared the databases before and after and only found differences on this particular table act_ru_job. Ive copied it on the remote server, and it worked

Comment: When you say blocks, do you mean the business process doesn't run as expected? or the application hangs? If the application hangs again, try taking a thread dump, it will give you some useful data points. It is hard to diagnose this issue by just looking at the database tables. The state of your tables could be a side effect of the issue not the cause of it.